# How to turn a series of if statements into a for or foreach loop?

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# for a course I'm taking. My current assignment is to build a gym membership form. I have it working but I keep thinking there must be a better way to do one of my functions.

I have a checklist of extras for the gym:

- 24/7 access
- Diet consult
- Rentals
- PT

Each has a value associated. If the diet is checked then $20 is added onto the base membership etc. Currently, I have it set up like this (which works):

```
private double calculateExtra()
    {           
        //this section adds extra charges to the base membership cost

        extraCost = 0;
        if (accessCheck.Checked)
        {
            extraCost += 1;
        }
        if (personalTrainerCheck.Checked)
        {
            extraCost += 20;
        }
        if (dietConsultCheck.Checked)
        {
            extraCost += 20;
        }
        if (fitnessVidCheck.Checked)
        {
            extraCost += 2;
        }
        return extraCost;
    }
```

Can someone please help me understand how to change this into a for loop or a foreach loop? I've been searching; I tried doing it as an array, but got confused with the values needing to be added, etc.

The output goes into a text box on a form once a calculate button has been pressed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have, although if you have more checkboxes it could get a little verbose. You could add your checkbox instances to a `Dictionary<CheckBox,int>` or `List<(CheckBox,int)>` after form construction, You could then iterate through that list to check for `Checked` and the value ect. Another approach would be to store the cost in the CheckBox Tag, and iterate through all checkboxes on the form, though in all honestly that is not really the best approach, hacky, and harder to maintain

Comment: @MichaelRandall - I was going to do an answer re using `List<(CheckBox,int)>`. Since you had the idea first do you want to?

Comment: @Enigmativity what matters more is who posts the answer as an answer first. Both people here seem to be experienced enough in the site to know better than to post an answer as a comment.

Comment: I think using `if`´s as you are makes the code simple and readable. I would keep it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do here is to introduce an enumerable (list, array, etc) that captures your checkboxes and the extra cost:

```
var checks = new []
{
    new { CheckBox = accessCheck, ExtraCost = 1, },
    new { CheckBox = personalTrainerCheck, ExtraCost = 20, },
    new { CheckBox = dietConsultCheck, ExtraCost = 20, },
    new { CheckBox = fitnessVidCheck, ExtraCost = 2, },
};
```

Now it's easy to add up the extra costs:

```
var extraCost = 0;
foreach (var check in checks)
{
    if (check.CheckBox.Checked)
    {
        extraCost += check.ExtraCost;
    }
}
return extraCost;
```

Now, if you want to make it a little more streamlined, then you could replace this computation with this:

```
return checks.Aggregate(0, (a, x) => x.CheckBox.Checked ? x.ExtraCost : 0);
```

The next issue that comes up is that the condition become more complicated, like `healthCheck.Checked && dietConsultCheck.Checked` or `location == "CBD" && fitnessVidCheck.Checked`. You can then do this:

```
var checks = new (Func<bool> Condition, int ExtraCost)[]
{
    (() => accessCheck.Checked, 1),
    (() => personalTrainerCheck.Checked, 20),
    (() => healthCheck.Checked && dietConsultCheck.Checked, 20),
    (() => location == "CBD" && fitnessVidCheck.Checked, 1),
};
return checks.Aggregate(0, (a, x) => x.Condition() ? x.ExtraCost : 0);
```

Finally,

if you wanted to be able to change what gets checked you can build this up at run-time if you change from an array to a list and promote `checks` to a field.

```
private List<(Func<bool> Condition, int ExtraCost)> _checks = null;
```

Then, at start up, you can set the defaults:

```
_checks = new List<(Func<bool> Condition, int ExtraCost)>()
{
    (() => accessCheck.Checked, 1),
    (() => personalTrainerCheck.Checked, 20),
    (() => healthCheck.Checked && dietConsultCheck.Checked, 20),
    (() => location == "CBD" && fitnessVidCheck.Checked, 1),
};
```

Now you're free to add more when you like:

```
_checks.Add((() => monthlySpecialCheck.Checked, -10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example, using a specialized class object that handles (or, can be easily modified to) all the operations related to the selection of these CheckBoxes.

The class object is build using an `IEnumerable((CheckBox, decimal))` and creates a `Dictionary<CheckBox, Func<decimal>` out of it.

The `Func<decimal>` returns the value associated to a CheckBox and performs other operations if needed or requested. In this case, as an example, it adds the VAT to the price if the `AddVAT` property is set to true. This property can be changed at any time and all values will be recalculated and returned by the public `GetSelectedServicesExtras()` method.

```
private class ExtraServices
{
    private Dictionary<CheckBox, Func<decimal>> services = null;
    public ExtraServices(IEnumerable<(CheckBox uiElement, decimal assocPrice)> servicePrices)
    {
        services = new Dictionary<CheckBox, Func<decimal>>();
        foreach (var service in servicePrices) {
            services.Add(service.uiElement, ()=>
                AddVAT ? service.assocPrice + (service.assocPrice * VAT / 100) 
                       : service.assocPrice
            );
        }
    }

    public decimal VAT { get; set; } = 10.00M;
    public bool AddVAT { get; set; } = false;

    public decimal GetSelectedServicesExtras()
    {
        return services.Aggregate(0.0M, (sum, elm) => 
            sum += elm.Key.Checked ? elm.Value() : 0M);
    }
}
```

Now, to initialize this class, you can add your CheckBoxes and the associated value (here I'm using `decimal` instead of `int` because these are actually Currency values, so it's possible to add a VAT which will include decimals of course).

```
private ExtraServices extras = null;
private decimal extrasTotal = 0.0m;

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    extras = new ExtraServices(new[] {
        (chkAccess, 1.0m),
        (chkPersonalTrainer, 20.0m),
        (chkDietConsult, 20.0m),
        (chkFitnessVid, 2.0m),
    }) { AddVAT = false };

    // Sets the initial values to 0.0m and formats the output
    CalculateExtras();
}
```

<sub>The *naming convention* of the CheckBoxes is slightly different here: I, personally, prefer to prefix the name with the type, as in `chkAccess`. I find this kind of *organization* simpler to handle. Just my preference.</sub>

All the CheckBoxes use the same `CheckedChanged` event handler.
When the event is raised by one of the Controls, the total value of the extra services is calculated, stored in a Field (`extrasTotal`) and a TextBox is updated, formatting the value to a Currency representation.

The *extra* CheckBox, `chkAddVAT`, is used to show that the VAT calculation can be turned On/Off at any time. A similar method can be used for other associated Controls, extending the **`ExtraServices`** class functionality to include the selection of all services and associated prices and automate the whole process.

```
private void chkExtras_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculateExtras();
}

private void chkAddVAT_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    extras.AddVAT = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;
    CalculateExtras();
}

private void CalculateExtras()
{
    extrasTotal = extras.GetSelectedServicesExtras();
    txtExtrasTotal.Text = extrasTotal.ToString("C");
}
```

`decimal.ToString("C")` formats the decimal value using the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` format. You can specify a different `CultureInfo`, if needed:
e.g., `decimal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))`

This is how it works:

[image: UI Controls Functional Aggregation]

Comment: Hey Jimi thank you very much. I have to say this is a little over my head for where I'm at right now but I'm certainly going to study this and use it as a learning tool. I really appreciate your time in answering this and creating the display. I think other people will also benefit a lot from your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, no problem. This a somewhat *classic* method, it comes in handy when you have to handle an undetermined number of Control that perform the same action and *automate* this action. If you need to add another Control, you add a new element to the Collection when you create the handler (the ExtraServices class, here). Nothing else is needed. No other code in your Forms, Controllers or Presenter. I see Enigmativity has posted something relatively similar in concept. Try to use these methods instead of adding tons of `if/elseif` blocks in your code that you then have to manage *manually*.